# Unable to fetch result set in Batches using ScrollableResults

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, entitymanager

I need to filter out data from Postgres database table . The query can return millions of data so it is not possible to keep data in memory as it will cause OOME . I tried using ScrollableResult to fetch data in batches but a single query is being fired as seen in logs . The following snippet is used to generate .

```
@Transactional
public void getObjectUsingScrollable() {
    String statement = "select t1.name,t2.address from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1Id WHERE t1.status='OPEN' ORDER BY t1.date DESC "
    StatelessSession session = ((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
    org.hibernate.query.Query query = session
            .createNativeQuery(statement);
    query.setFetchSize(5);
    query.setReadOnly(true);
    query.setLockMode("t1", LockMode.READ);
    query.setCacheable(false);
    ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    while (results.next()) {
        Object obj=results.get(0);
    }
    results.close();
    session.close();
}
```

I have tried using LockMode.NONE .
Why doesn't this fire up a query after every 5th iteration of while loop?
Hibernate Version- 5.4.18
Postgres Version - 9.4-1200-jdbc41

Comment: May be due to query.setFetchSize(5) line? Try changing to 10 and check.

Comment: @Alien I have tried with the following values for fetchSize. 5,50,500.

Comment: Ok.. how many rows plain sql query returns in postgres console?

Comment: @Alien 5630 rows.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how scrollable results work, you will see only one query. The fetch size is just a hint for the JDBC driver to fetch only that many rows per round-trip to the database.

Essentially, a scrollable result is like an open cursor on the database where you fetch N (fetch size) elements. The driver serves you these rows and when you request more, it might fetch the next N rows through the cursor.

Using the code you have shown, you shouldn't get an OOME unless you keep the data around somewhere. At least Hibernate will not hold on to the data this way.

Comment: Thanks For the explanation . And if there is an exception in the second round trip to DB , will the open cursor release DB connection . As I am getting an issue sometimes that Hikari pool is exhausted . results.next() throws NullPointerException . The same sql query returns data in DB but still results.next() throws NPE. And after this exception a second call to the same method throws Exception that Hikari pool has been exhausted .

Comment: I don't know what your code does, but if you don't close the connection (note that connection pools like Hikari usually return a connection proxy), it won't be returned to the connection pool. If you face an exception and forget to close resources, the connection might be lost. You probably need `try { ... } finally { session.close(); }`